# Query Builder update statement with current value in addition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Is it possible to update tables with the current value in addition?

```
Model::where('rgt', '>=', $this->rgt)->update(array(
   'rgt' => 'rgt' + 2 // or 'rgt + 2'
));
```

The result is always 2, i want to refer to the row rgt like this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE model SET rgt=rgt+2 WHERE rgt >= 2;
```

In the laravel [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#updates) i can't find anything concrete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `increment` should take care of that:

```
Model::where('rgt', '>=', $this->rgt)->increment('rgt', $this->rgt));
```